# MySqlDataAdapter SelectCommand Statement

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have the following functional code:

```
Call ConnSettings()
Dim objDs As New DataSet
Dim Query As String
Query = "the query"

Cmd = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
Dim dAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
dAdapter.SelectCommand = Cmd

''Dim dAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(Query, MysqlConn)

Try
   MysqlConn.Open()
   dAdapter.Fill(objDs)
   MysqlConn.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
Finally
   MysqlConn.Dispose()
End Try
```

I have noticed that the code is equally functional if I also use

```
Dim dAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(Query, MysqlConn)
```

instead of:

```
Cmd = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
Dim dAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
dAdapter.SelectCommand = Cmd
```

Obviously, I would like to use a single line instead of three. However, I am fairly new to VB and would like to know if there are any issues with doing that.

Comment: No, that's way is the usual one used by a lot of code. Differences are meaningless

Comment: If it works, it works.  DataAdapters can open and close the connection, so you don't need the MysqlConn.Open and MysqlConn.Close when using them.

Comment: I will be more concerned instead about your habit to use global variables instead. That ConnSettings should return a MySqlConnection so you could enclose it in a Using Statement and remove the try/finally block. Also other global variables like the command are just a source of troubles and doesn't have any meaningful effect on performance or memory.

Comment: Thank you @Steve. I perform other queries to the database in other Private Subs and I reckoned that instead of declaring the ConnSettings() each time, I would do it once. Does this alleviate the concerns, please advise. Secondly, would you provide additional feedback about the try/finally block?

Comment: Connection objects should be created, used and disposed as needed.  A global connection string is fine, or a function returning a connection.  The overload `(Query, MysqlConn)`  are nice because you cant forget to initialize them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try to improve your code....

First ConnSettings doesn't initialize a global connection variable but a local one and returns it

```
Public Function ConnSettings() As MySqlConnection
    Dim conn As MySqlConnection
    conn = new MySqlConnection(yourConnectionStringHere)
    conn.Open()
    return conn
End Function
```

Now the code that needs a MySqlConnection could call this ConnSettings and put the return value in a Using Statement

```
objDS = new DataSet()
Try
    Using conn = ConnSettings()
    Using dAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(theQuery, conn)
       dAdapter.Fill(objDs)
    End Using
    End Using
Catch(ex as Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

This code puts the connection returned in a Using Statement. When the code flows out of the Using Statement the connection is closed and disposed (same for the MySqlDataAdapter) As you can see there is no need for the Finally clause and the Try/Catch block is present just because you want to give an error message to your user (while this is a common practice there is no really sense to put your user in the unconfortable position to try to understand these technically dense messages, better use a log file and advise your user to send the log to you)

In this context also the code inside the ConnSettings is a bit useless. What you really need is just the connectionstring and you could write the creation of the MySqlConnection directly in the calling code.